# Renaming names in a file using another file without using loops

Tags: perl, matlab, sed, awk, grep

I have two files:

(one.txt) looks Like this:

```
>ENST001 

(((....)))

(((...)))

>ENST002 

(((((((.......))))))

((((...)))
```

I have like 10000 more ENST

(two.txt) looks like this:

```
>ENST001   110

>ENST002  59
```

and so on for the rest of all ENSTs

I basically would like to replace the ENSTs in the (one.txt) by the combination of the two fields in the (two.txt) so the results will look like this:

```
>ENST001_110 

(((....)))

(((...)))

>ENST002_59 

(((((((.......))))))

((((...)))
```

I wrote a matlab script to do so but since it loops for all lines in (two.txt) it take like 6 hours to finish, so I think using awk, sed, grep, or even perl we can get the result in few minutes. This is what I did in matlab:

```
frf = fopen('one.txt', 'r');       
frp = fopen('two.txt', 'r');                                     
fw = fopen('result.txt', 'w');    

while feof(frf) == 0

line = fgetl(frf);
first_char = line(1);

if strcmp(first_char, '>') == 1 % if the line in one.txt start by > it is the ID 

   id_fold = strrep(line, '>', ''); % Reomve the > symbol


   frewind(frp)     % Rewind two.txt file after each loop

    while feof(frp) == 0

        raw = fgetl(frp);
        scan = textscan(raw, '%s%s');
        id_pos = scan{1}{1};
        pos = scan{2}{1};

            if strcmp(id_fold, id_pos) == 1  % if both ids are the same


                id_new = ['>', id_fold, '_', pos];

                fprintf(fw, '%s\n', id_new);

            end    

    end    

else

    fprintf(fw, '%s\n', line);  % if the line doesn't start by > print it to results



end
```

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed` you can at first run only on `two.txt` you can make a `sed` commands to replace as you want and run it at `one.txt`:

**First way**

```
sed "$(sed -n '/>ENST/{s=.*\(ENST[0-9]\+\)\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*=s/\1/\1_\2/;=;p}' two.txt)" one.txt
```

**Second way**

If files are huge you'll get `too many arguments error` with previous way. Therefore there is another way to fix this error. You need execute all three commands one by one:

```
sed -n '1i#!/bin/sed -f
/>ENST/{s=.*\(ENST[0-9]\+\)\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*=s/\1/\1_\2/;=;p}' two.txt > script.sed
chmod +x script.sed
./script.sed one.txt
```

The first command will form the sed script that will be able to modify one.txt as you want. `chmod` will make this new script executable. And the last command will execute command. So each file is read only once. There is no any loops.
Note that first command consist from two lines, but still is one command. If you'll delete newline character it will break the script. It is because of `i` command in `sed`. You can look for details in ``sed man page.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I wrote second part of my answer about running via file. Try it, it should work fine. Note that you must have newline character after `-f`. Otherwise it won't work correct.

Comment: file one.txt in your second part is missd

Comment: Nope. It isn't. Ok, I've updated my post to make it a little bit clear.

Answer (score 4):

One way using `awk`. `FNR == NR` process first file in arguments and saves each number. Second condition process second file, and when first field matches with a key in the array modifies that line appending the number.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { 
        data[ $1 ] = $2; 
        next 
    } 
    FNR < NR && data[ $1 ] { 
        $0 = $1 "_" data[ $1 ] 
    } 
    { print }
' two.txt one.txt
```

Output:

```
>ENST001_110

(((....)))

(((...)))

>ENST002_59

(((((((.......))))))

((((...)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This Perl solution sends the modified `one.txt` file to `STDOUT`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $f2, '<', 'two.txt' or die $!;

my %ids;

while (<$f2>) {
  $ids{$1} = "$1_$2" if /^>(\S+)\s+(\d+)/;
}

open my $f1, '<', 'one.txt' or die $!;

while (<$f1>) {
  s/^>(\S+)\s*$/>$ids{$1}/;
  print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the problem on its head.  In perl I would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(FH1, "one.txt");
open(FH2, "two.txt");
open(RESULT, ">result.txt");

my %data;

while (my $line = <FH2>)
{
    chomp(line);

    # Delete leading angle bracket
    $line =~ s/>//d;

    # split enst and pos
    my ($enst, $post) = split(/\s+/, line);

    # Store POS with ENST as key
    $data{$enst} = $pos;
}

close(FH2);

while (my $line = <FH1>)
{
    # Check line for ENST
    if ($line =~ m/^>(ENST\d+)/)
    {
        my $enst = $1;

            # Get pos for ENST
        my $pos = $data{$enst};

            # make new line
        $line = '>' . $enst . '_' . $pos . '\n';
    }

    print RESULT $line;
}

close(FH1);
close(RESULT);
```

Comment: You should use the three-argument-version of `open` and lexical filehandles. And always start a script with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^$/!s|^\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\).*|s/^\1.*/\1_\2/|p' two.txt | sed -f - one.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this MATLAB solution (no loops):

```
%# read files as cell array of lines
fid = fopen('one.txt','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','\n');
C1 = C{1};
fclose(fid);
fid = fopen('two.txt','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','\n');
C2 = C{1};
fclose(fid);

%# use regexp to extract ENST numbers from both files
num = regexp(C1, '>ENST(\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
idx1 = find(~cellfun(@isempty, num));       %# location of >ENST line
val1 = str2double([num{:}]);                %# ENST numbers
num = regexp(C2, '>ENST(\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
idx2 = find(~cellfun(@isempty, num));
val2 = str2double([num{:}]);

%# construct new header lines from file2
C2(idx2) = regexprep(C2(idx2), ' +','_');

%# replace headers lines in file1 with the new headers
[tf,loc] = ismember(val2,val1);
C1( idx1(loc(tf)) ) = C2( idx2(tf) );

%# write result
fid = fopen('three.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n',C1{:});
fclose(fid);
```